# Cloud Firestore collections queries not working

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As Cloud Firestore is new, I am having problems using it.

I have to get **Collection** of all **users** and traverse it. But it is not working.

```
db.collection("users").get().then(function(querySnapshot){
      console.log(querySnapshot.data());
});
```

It says:

> querySnapshot.data is not a function

And following code:

```
callFireBase(mobileToCheck){
        db.collection("users").where("mobile_no", '==', mobileToCheck).get().then(function(querySnapshot){
            if (querySnapshot.exists) {
                var userData = querySnapshot.data();
                var userId = querySnapshot.id;
                console.log(mobileToCheck + "Exist In DB");
            }else{
                console.log(mobileToCheck + "Do Not Exist In DB");
            }
        });
}
```

Is always printing

> 923052273575 Do Not Exist In DB

Even if it exists, See following image for reference.

[image]

Comment: @ Noman Ali did you get the solution for these query

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you have some things confused as querySnapshot doesn't have `data`, but it does have `docs` which have data.

In your first example, you are asking it to return all documents in the collection. You'll want something like this instead:

```
db.collection("users").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

Key difference is looping over the docs in `querySnapshot` and console logging the data from each doc.

For your second example, you'll want to check if the `querySnapshot` is empty, rather than checking if it exists.

```
db.collection("users").where("mobile_no", "==", mobileToCheck)
.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    if (querySnapshot.exists) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            var userData = doc.data()
            var userId = doc.id
            console.log(mobileToCheck + "Exist In DB");
        });
    } else {
        console.log(mobileToCheck + "Do Not Exist In DB");
    };
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

Comment: @ Dan McGrath I have used the above query But for me it always says user does not exist. But number is in database . Whats the problem

Comment: I know this is old but querySnapshot does not have a .exists method as Dan said. you need to check if querySnapShot is empty - !querySnapShot.empty